# OSX/Cocoa - NSScrollView with transparent background

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, background-color, nsscrollview

I can't seem to create a NSScrollView with a transparent background. Does anyone know why?
here is my code:

```
NSScrollView *textScroll = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(212, 203, 381, 55)];
[textScroll setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
[view addSubview:textScroll];
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think in your case this should work:

```
[textScroll setDrawsBackground:NO];
```